# Logging process' CPU utilisation

Tags: windows, hyper-v

following problem deals with MS Windows Server 2008 R2 with Hyper-V:

Does anybody have an idea how to log processes which cause CPU utilisation more than X percent? I want to uncover an unexpected CPU load peak problem which occurs once a day in a regular fashion. Since it's a terminal server, all network connections time out and bandwidth tends to zero.

Answer (score 1):

You have to observe vCPU utilisation from outside the VM using whatever tools are available to you, vCPU measurements inside any VM are suspect at best.